# How To Change Login & Register View in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm new to Laravel, so here I want to make a view for login and register, and then I change the default view login and register into my own view, I changed it in the route and then it work, and then I try to run this code: `php artisan ui:auth` and then my login view before, it changes to the default view of Laravel. How to change it again into my login and view design ? Thank you.

This is my route web.php:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('pages/home');
});

Route::get('/register','Auth\AuthController@register');
Route::post('/register','Auth\AuthController@postRegister')->name('register');

Route::get('/login','AuthController@login');
Route::post('/login','AuthController@postLogin')->name('login');
```

and this is my AuthController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\User;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;

class AuthController extends Controller
{

    public function register()
    {
        return view('login_register/register');
    }


    public function postRegister(Request $request )
    {
        User::create([
            'name'=> $request->nama,
            'email'=> $request->email,
            'password'=> bcrypt($request->password)

        ]);
           return redirect('/login');
    }


    public function login()
    {
        return view('login_register/login');
    }

    public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
        if(!\Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password ])){
            return redirect()->back();
        }

         return redirect('/galangdana/list');
    }







public function redirectToProvider($provider)
    {
        return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
    }

    /**
     * Obtain the user information from provider.  Check if the user already exists in our
     * database by looking up their provider_id in the database.
     * If the user exists, log them in. Otherwise, create a new user then log them in. After that
     * redirect them to the authenticated users homepage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
        $authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($user, $provider);
        Auth::login($authUser, true);
        return redirect('/');
    }

    /**
     * If a user has registered before using social auth, return the user
     * else, create a new user object.
     * @param  $user Socialite user object
     * @param $provider Social auth provider
     * @return  User
     */
    public function findOrCreateUser($user, $provider)
    {
        $authUser = User::where('provider_id', $user->id)->first();
        if ($authUser) {
            return $authUser;
        }
        else{
            $data = User::create([
                'name'     => $user->name,
                'email'    => !empty($user->email)? $user->email : '' ,
                'provider' => $provider,
                'provider_id' => $user->id
            ]);
            return $data;
        }
    }



}

?>
```

Comment: So what is your issue Please explain

Comment: my problem is, i want to change the login and register view into my own view, i've been change the url of /login into my login view, but it still direct into login view of laravel

Comment: if you look in your `resources/views/auth` you will find the laravel auth views in there. Replace with your own.

Comment: @DidikAriyana This issue occurs after `php artisan ui:auth` run command, right?
Before this command, everything is fine yes?

Comment: yes before i'm run that command, my login view was changed, so i've been check using route:list and there two uri of login http://prntscr.com/pz0faq

Comment: Do you also have more routes to /login and /register, get and post? Also, is there an Auth::routes() in the route file?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `showLoginForm()` method, in you `LoginController.php`:

```php
public function showLoginForm()
{
    return view('my.view');
}
```

It overrides the function `showLoginForm` defined in the trait `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers`.

For registration, you `showRegistrationForm` method, defined in `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers` trait:

```php
public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    return view('my.register.view');
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think OP already did some changes and ran ui:auth command again, which will override the changes back to original laravel code.

Answer (score -1):

solved, that becasue i put Auth::routes() so that make multiple login, thank you for the answer

Comment: This is a comment not an answer